# Executing a swf animation on entering a website and fading it out to the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twig

I have made an animation with Flash CC 2015 and I would like to make it appear when entering a website.
I am a student and I started working with Twig not so long ago so that confuses me even more.
I have succeeded to embed it in Html file like that:
In the "head" of my layout.html.twig file, I have

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var flashvars = {};
    var params = {};
    var attributes = {};


    params.bgcolor = "#FFFFFF";

    attributes.name = "";
    attributes.styleclass = "";
    attributes.align = "";
    swfobject.embedSWF("Brainca5.swf", "flashContent", "1520", "682", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params,
        attributes);
</script>
```

And at the top of my home.html.twig file, I have

```
<div id="flashContent">
    Get <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">Adobe Flash Player</a>. Embedded with the help of <a href="http://embed-swf.org">embed-swf.org</a>.
</div>
```

so I see the animation, but now, what I would like to do is that it appears only when entering the website. I would like that it to appear alone and only when the animation is finished that the content of the website and home page appear.

In fact, I am even more frustrated using Twig as the animation has to cover all the page(header and footer too) and I really don't see how as using the Twig template the header and footer are in the layout.html.twig and are common for all the pages and as I want it to appear only when entering the website I thought that the swf embed should be positioned in the home.html.twig. But again, one more thing with that is when already on the website and consulting another page if one decides to go on the home page the animation shouldn't play again.

Well, after a couple of days I have succeeded to make it appear without the other content and then disappear to let the other content appear.
I have changed the embed file with the file generated from Flash, but I think it could have worked as well with the embed file.
So now in my layout.html.twig I have

```
<body onload="init();">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1520" height="682" style="background-color:#FFFFFF">
  </canvas>
  <div id="sadarjanie" style="display: none;">
<header>
<nav>
</nav>
</header>
<section>
</section>
<footer>
</footer>
</body>
```

And a javascript file

```
var canvas, stage, exportRoot;

function init() {
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
images = images||{};
ss = ss||{};

var loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
loader.addEventListener("fileload", handleFileLoad);
loader.addEventListener("complete", handleComplete);
loader.loadFile({src:"images/Brainca5_atlas_.json", type:"spritesheet", 
id:"Brainca5_atlas_"}, true);
loader.loadManifest(lib.properties.manifest);
}

function handleFileLoad(evt) {
if (evt.item.type == "image") { images[evt.item.id] = evt.result; }
}

function handleComplete(evt) {
var queue = evt.target;
ss["Brainca5_atlas_"] = queue.getResult("Brainca5_atlas_");
exportRoot = new lib.Brainca1();

stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
stage.addChild(exportRoot);
stage.update();

createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
setTimeout(function() {
$('#canvas').fadeOut('slow');
}, 11000);
setTimeout(function() {
$( "#sadarjanie" ).fadeIn( 'slow');}, 11000);
}
```

So now my main problem remains that the animation doesn't charge on every page once we navigate the website but only when entering the website. And as you see for the  with #sadarjanie I have display:none; so that it shows after the animation with the fadeIn in jQuery but it shouldn't be considered when the animation is not shown.
Thank you!

Comment: I don't see what you are trying to tell? I ask as I just started coding and I am learning now. So I am looking for a little help.

Comment: My point is that what you're trying to do ("Flash intro") is extremely outdated. Flash just isn't used on the internet much, if at all, any more, because HTML5 solves pretty much all of the problems that Flash did but better. Additionally, user expectations have changed. If it takes more than a second to get to the content of your page, people are gonna close your site and find something more useful to do with their time. You're setting yourself up to fail hard.

Comment: Well, I wanted to do an animation for a website. I have no one to ask and I didn't know how to do it. So, I looked what was written on the internet and I have done this. I don't think that I could have done an SVG animation without any help at all. I think you are right for the time of charging but I wanted to experiment with animation for web.